# How to change value of label depending on criteria

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a label called `lblScore.Text` and `lblScore.Text = iCorrectACount.ToString();` where `iCorrectACount` is basically a counter of how many questions a user answered right. Now what I want to do is basically make it so that this number multiplies the end score depending on the difficulty chosen i.e. if easy questions are chosen, multiply `iCorrectACount` by 0 and cast to string, if medium questions are chosen, multiply `iCorrectACount` by 1.5 and cast to string and if hard questions are chosen, multiply `iCorrectACount` by 2 and cast to string, but I'm not sure how I'd do this.

My code is like this:

```
private void QuizReset()
{
    // Resets the difficulty selection control and shows it again upon resetting the quiz
    difficultySelectionControl.Reset();
    difficultySelectionControl.BringToFront();

    // Disabled the 'Next' button and prompts the user to select a difficulty - User cannot continue without choosing
    btnNext.Enabled = false;
    lblStatus.Text = "Please select a difficulty";

    // Sets the number of questions and correct answers to zero
    iCorrectACount = 0;
    iCurrentQIndex = 0;
}

private void LoadQuestions(Difficulty difficulty)
{
    // Defines a random variable to be used to shuffle the order of the questions and answers
    var rand = new Random();
    // Loads the corresponding XML document with 'Easy', 'Medium' or 'Hard' questions depending on difficulty chosen
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(GetFileNameFor(difficulty));

    // List of questions that are filtered from the XML file based on them being wrapped in question tags
    _questions = xdoc.Descendants("question")
        .Select(q => new Question()
        {
            ID = (int)q.Attribute("id"),
            Difficulty = (int)q.Attribute("difficulty"),
            QuestionText = (string)q.Element("text"),
            Answers = q.Element("answers")
                .Descendants()
                // Stores all answers into a string
                .Select(a => (string)a)
                // Randomizing answers
                .OrderBy(a => rand.Next()) 
                .ToArray(),
            CorrectAnswer = (string)q.Element("answers")
                .Descendants("correctAnswer")
                // Use value instead of index
                .First() 
        })
        // Selects questions that match the difficulty integer of the option the user chose
        .Where(q => q.Difficulty == (int)difficulty + 1)
        // Randomizing questions
        .OrderBy(q => rand.Next())
        .ToList(); 

    lblStatus.Text = String.Format("There are {0} questions in this section", _questions.Count);
}

private string GetFileNameFor(Difficulty difficulty)
{
    switch (difficulty)
    {
        case Difficulty.Easy: return "quiz_easy.xml";
        case Difficulty.Medium: return "quiz_medium.xml";
        case Difficulty.Hard: return "quiz_hard.xml";
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}       

private void PickQuestion()
{
    questionControl.DisplayQuestion(_questions[iCurrentQIndex]);
    questionControl.BringToFront();
    iCurrentQIndex++;
}

private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QuizReset();
    lblScore.Text = "0";
}

private void miNewQuiz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    QuizReset();
    lblScore.Text = "0";
}

private void miExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}

private void miHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormHowToPlay form = new FormHowToPlay(); 
    form.ShowDialog();
}

private void miAbout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AboutBox1 aboutForm = new AboutBox1();
    aboutForm.ShowDialog();
}

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (iCurrentQIndex < _questions.Count)
    {
        PickQuestion();
        lblStatus.Text = String.Format("Question {0} of {1}", iCurrentQIndex, _questions.Count);
    }
    else
    {
        btnNext.Enabled = false;
        lblStatus.Text = String.Format("You answered {0} questions correctly out of a possible {1}",
                                      iCorrectACount, _questions.Count);

        this.Hide();

        SummaryForm sumForm = new SummaryForm();
        DialogResult result = sumForm.ShowDialog();

        MenuForm mnuform = new MenuForm();
        mnuform.ShowDialog();
    }
}

    private void difficultySelectionControl_DifficultySelected(object sender, DifficultySelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        iCurrentQIndex = 0;
        LoadQuestions(e.Difficulty);           

        btnNext.Enabled = true;
    }  


    private void questionControl_QuestionAnswered(object sender, QuestionAnsweredEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsCorrect)
            iCorrectACount++;

        lblScore.Text = iCorrectACount.ToString();

    }
```

It's the last little thing I need to figure out and I can't figure out how to get it so that if the difficulty = easy/medium/hard, multiply `iCorrectAmount` by 1/1.5/2/0.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1):

in `difficultySelectionControl_DifficultySelected`, store the selected difficulty in a class variable, `m_difficulty`.
Then, just access it in `questionControl_QuestionAnswered`

in your class definition, add `private Difficulty m_difficulty`.
in `difficultySelectionControl_DifficultySelected`, add a line saying `m_difficulty = e.Difficulty`.
then, you can use that difficulty in your `questionControl_QuestionAnswered`, just like @Michael Perrenoud suggested.

Comment: Could you give an example? Not quite certain what you mean (Forgive me)

Comment: In which class definition do I add `private Difficulty m_difficulty`

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
int modifier = 1;
if (difficulty == Difficulty.Medium) { modifier = 1.5; }
if (difficulty == Difficulty.Hard) { modifier = 2; }

lblScore.Text = (iCorrectACount * modifier).ToString();
```

you'll need to get the `difficulty` from somewhere obviously, and I can't tell where exactly right now, but you have it because you passed it into the method `LoadQuestions` and `GetFileNameFor`, so just grab it, run the code, and BAM you got your modifier.

**NOTE:** I set the modifier to `1` by default, I'm pretty sure you didn't want to set it to `0` since that would net `0` as the result every time.