# Field is never assigned to and will always have its default value 0

Tags: c#, winforms

I get the following error in my code and I'm not sure why:

Warning - `'SummaryForm.m_difficulty' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0`

Code

```
public partial class SummaryForm : Form
{
    // Declares variables with the values pulled from the 'MainForm'
    int iCorrectACount = MainForm.iCorrectACount;
    int iCurrentQIndex = MainForm.iCurrentQIndex;

    private Difficulty m_difficulty;

    public SummaryForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        double modifier = 1.0;
        if (m_difficulty == Difficulty.Easy) { modifier = 1.0; }
        if (m_difficulty == Difficulty.Medium) { modifier = 1.5; }
        if (m_difficulty == Difficulty.Hard) { modifier = 2; }

        // Sets the labels using integer values
        lblCorrectNum.Text = iCorrectACount.ToString();
        lblWrongNum.Text = (iCurrentQIndex - iCorrectACount).ToString();
        lblScoreTotal.Text = (iCorrectACount * modifier).ToString();
    }
```

Maybe this has something to do with why `lblScoreTotal.Text` will not change to the value * modifier but will on another form?

The reason I asked this question here is because someone advised me to disable warning messages but I didn't think that was the appropriate solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to clarify it further for you. You start examining the contents of `m_difficulty` in your constructor, but nothing ever *sets* a value into that field.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is entirely correct: *nothing* is going to change your `m_difficulty` field, as far as you've shown. What do you *expect* to set that value? Did you actually mean to set it to something based on `MainForm` as per `iCorrectACount` and `iCurrentQIndex`?

How do you expect it would ever be anything other than whatever `(Difficulty) 0` evaluates as?

It's pretty dodgy to be pulling initial values from a statically-accessed instance of a form, too, IMO. It would be much better if the constructor accepted initial values from whatever was constructing it.

Comment: I want `m_difficulty` to equal either `Difficulty.Easy`, `Difficulty.Medium` or `Difficulty.Hard` depending on what the user picks (Three buttons that correspond to each difficulty level)

Comment: @user2141272: On the new form? Surely you should have an event for that radio-button (or whatever) being changed, and assign it there. But *in the constructor* it's never going to be a different value, right?

Comment: No, in the constructor it's not going to be different, just want it to reflect what the user has chosen. Each button has an event handler containing `OnDifficultySelected(Difficulty.Easy);` (Same for `Medium` and `Hard`)

Comment: @user2141272: But do you understand that the code you've presented isn't going to be run then. It's *only* going to be run when you create a new instance, when `m_difficulty` always has its default value. How do you expect `modifier` to be adjusted? What benefit do you expect the code in your constructor to have? It feels like you're confused about when the code in your constructor will be executed.

Comment: I am a little confused to be honest. It stems from this question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422270/how-to-change-value-of-label-depending-on-criteria

Comment: @user2141272: I think you should take a step back from your current actual task, and try to understand object life-cycles, constructors, event handlers etc. Then come back to your code, make sure you understand why the compiler is giving you a warning here, and then fix it.

Comment: I've fixed the code now after looking at it hehe. Thank you for your input though :)

Answer (score 4):

`m_difficulty` is private, so it can't be accessed from outside your class, but you never assign it inside, so it will never change.

Therefore, it makes no real sense to compare it, as it will always be equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should always initialize a variable after you declared it.

```
private Difficulty m_difficulty = new Difficulty();
```

Something like that.

So you prevent it to be null (in this case you would get an exception).

The warning just tells you this.

Comment: It's an enum, by the looks of it - there's no nullity involved here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're expecting m_difficulty to be bound to a dropdown selection on your user form.  It is not.  Even if it were, you would want to access the SelectedValue property instead of the object itself.  Maybe this is what you're looking for.

```
Difficulty m_difficulty = (Difficulty)Enum.Parse(ddDifficulty.SelectedValue);
```